# Usability for confirm message in a long form

Tags: forms, usability

I term of usability, I'm wondering what's the best solution to display my confirm message.

I have a long form, and in small screen I can't see the top of the form.
When I'm submitting my form, where is the best position for my message "Your information has been saved"?

- In the top of the form, and I add an automatic scroll up ?
- In the bottom close to the save button?
- In a dialog box?
- Other solutions?

I tried to find that on Internet but nothing really interesting. Please quote your source if you have an answer for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it reload the page resp. load a new page or gets the form submitted "inline" (with JS)?

Comment: The page is not reloaded, it's sent using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only place in your application that has this functionality, it doesn't matter so much; if you already have it working one way or the other somewhere else, consistency is the most important.

Where will the user need to navigate to next?  If navigation is at the top, auto-scrolling them to the top and showing a message there might be appropriate.

If the navigation is on the left side, auto-scrolling will lose the user's place in the page, which will make navigation harder.  In this case, tell them right next to the submit button.

If there's only *one* place they can navigate to next, skip the AJAX and do an interstitial "success!" screen that also takes them to the next place they'll want to navigate.

But most of all?  Consistency with the rest of your app.